# Facing Error - "Cannot create file EditorLayout_SQL.lay. Access is denied" while trying to connect to any schema in TOAD for Oracle 9.5 Ver

Tags: oracle11g, toad

I had installed TOAD long time back without the 32 bit Oracle Client. Though I had installed 64 bit Oracle 11g Client, TOAD only looks for 32 bit Oracle Client because TOAD itself is a 32 bit application and only works with 32 bit Oracle Client.
So I installed Oracle Client 32 bit and I was able to logon to Database Schema. But as soon as I say connect, this below error pops up. Though am connected successfully to the schema, this error shows up time and again on some actions taken on TOAD screen. 
The file named EditorLayout_SQL.lay mentioned in error is present in the Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\User Files folder and I am logged into this 64 bit OS Windows Server 2008 R2 machine having TOAD, as Administrator without any rights / permissions restrictions but even so this persistent error was coming.

> Error.
> Cannot create file ~\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\User Files\EditorLayout_SQL.lay. Access is denied

Comment: probably oracle user has not write rights to directory `~\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\User Files\`, verify the access rights for the user oracle

Comment: Even I thought that its write permissions issue but that was not the case. Below is the answer I gave to my own question. That's how I was able to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is -
Go to the location specified in the error.
From there copy the file mentioned in error i.e., EditorLayout_SQL.lay and paste it in some other backup folder, say in D Drive.
Now delete this file from the original toad location.
Restart TOAD. Voila, the error is gone.
Thing is this file EditorLayout_SQL.lay is to be created / updated each time the user logs on to TOAD. Since the file was already there, TOAD was unable to create / replace it. This could happen if the TOAD user files were copied from one TOAD profile to another instead of keeping the default installed folder structure.
You can recheck this folder after running TOAD and there you will find that a fresh EditorLayout_SQL.lay was successfully created in place of the one that we had removed earlier.